# How to open Screen sideways in Android?? (the screen animation part)

Tags: android, android-fragments, twitter, android-animation

In Twitter app when you click a tweet the screen just slides to left like a page is sliding. This is I think the Animation part. I want that in my app but couldn't find anything on this. In my app there are many fragments which add/remove many times. There are buttons on each fragment and when I click a button new fragment comes up. I want them to slide like a page just like in twitter. I know ViewPager class but this is something different. Please help me.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You could put all fragments in a `linearlayout` that is aligned horizontally.

Set the `weight` of one of your fragments to one, and all others to zero.
Now set up an animation, using Thread.sleep(), in which you slowly increase the weight of the next fragment from 0 to 1, while simultaneously decreasing the weight of the other fragment from 1 to 0.

Comment: I didn't get it. My all fragments(Layouts) are in vertical orientation. When i click a button a new fragment comes up. The code is: 
`code`
ShopMainFragment shopMainFragment= ShopMainFragment.newInstance();
                Fragment oldFragment = fm.findFragmentById(R.id.fragmentContainer);
                fm.beginTransaction()
                        .remove(oldFragment)
                        .add(R.id.fragmentContainer, shopMainFragment)
                        .commit();`code`
This way new fragment: shopMainFragment come up and old one removed.